# SpringSecurity: ifAnyGranted roles as property

Tags: jsf, spring-security, roles

how is it possible to pass the allowed roles as property?:

```
<sec:ifAnyGranted roles="#{item.allowedRolesToRender}">
```

Where Item is not a bean but the var of an dataList:

```
<rich:dataList value="${handler.itemlist}" var="item"
```

I tried to return array/comma-separated-string/list but it seems the the get method is never called. And i always get:

```
com.sun.facelets.FaceletException: roles must be given
at org.springframework.security.taglibs.facelets.IfAnyGrantedTag.apply(IfAnyGrantedTag.java:41)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like this.

```
<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="#{item.allowedRolesToRender}">
```

And allowedRolesToRender should be given as a comma-separated list of strings

[Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-faces.html#spring-faces-security-taglib)